# How do you handle nested source data with AVRO serialization in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

My goal is to grab JSON data from an HTTP source and store it in a Kafka topic using AVRO serialization.

Using Kafka Connect and an [HTTP source connector](https://github.com/castorm/kafka-connect-http) along with a bunch of SMTs, I managed to create a Connect data structure that looks like this when written to the topic with the StringConverter:

> Struct{base=stations,cod=200,coord=Struct{lat=54.0,lon=9.0},dt=1632150605}

Thus the JSON was successfully parsed into STRUCTs and I can manipulate individual elements using SMTs. Next, I created a new subject with the corresponding schema inside the Confluent Schema Registry and switched the connector's value converter over to the Confluent AVRO Converter with `"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"`.

Instead of the expected serialization I got an error message saying:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
> Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: **Can't redefine: io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault**

As soon as I remove the nested STRUCT with ReplaceField or simplify the structure with Flatten, the AVRO serialization works like a charm. So it looks like the converter cannot handle nested structures.

What is the right way to go when you have nested elements and want them to be serialized as such rather than storing the JSON as a String and trying to deal with object creation in the consumer or beyond? Is this possible in Kafka Connect?

Comment: Avro can handle nested records fine. The problem you're running into is the deserializer cannot handle duplicate/repeated namespaced records with different fields... There's some "set schema metadata" transform, you might want to look at

Comment: This transformed the exception to `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema`. So it looks like that solves the initial issue, but I'm still not quite there. The schema it spells out in the message is the same as in the Schema Registry, character for character. What else does it look for to match the schema?

Comment: Retrieving by id? The schema text shouldn't matter all too much, but I've not personally used the transform I mentioned. Also, that exception seems to be before the deserializer, not during like your other error

Comment: Can only retrieve by name and version, but that works **only if** you include the additional entries `connect.name` and `connect.version` in your schema definition. Something which I have not seen documented anywhere.
Unfortunately, I'm kind of back to square one. The inner STRUCT `coord` is still parsed as `io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault` by the `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer` so as soon as I add a second inner STRUCT of differing type I get the original error. Thus I'd need to be able to set the metadata for each nested element... but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of STRUCT elements from a JSON String can be achieved by different means. Originally, the SMT [ExpandJson](https://github.com/RedHatInsights/expandjsonsmt) was used for its simplicity. It does not create sufficiently named STRUCTs, however, as it doesn't have a schema to work off of. And that is what caused the initial error message as the AVRO serializer uses the generic class `io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault` for those STRUCTs and if there is more than one there is ambiguity, which throws an exception.

Another SMT doing seemingly the same thing is [Json Schema](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-json-schema/index.html), which has a documented FromJson conversion. It does accept a schema and thus gets around ExpandJson's problem of parsing nested elements as a generic type. What is being accepted is a JSON Schema, though, and the mapping to AVRO fullnames works by taking the word "properties" as the namespace and copying the field name. In this example, you would end up with `properties.coord` as the fullname of the inner element.

As an example, when the following JSON Schema is passed to the SMT:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "coord": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "lon": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "lat": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "lon",
        "lat"
      ]
    },
    ...
}
```

The AVRO schema it produces (and thus looks for in the Schema Registry) is:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        ...
        {
            "name": "coord",
            "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "coord",
                "namespace": "properties",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "lat",
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "lon",
                        "type": "double"
                    }
                ],
                "connect.name": "properties.coord"
            }
        },
    ...
}
```

In theory, if you have another schema with a `coord` element on the second level, it will get the same fullname, but since these are not individual entries inside the Schema Registry needing to be referenced, this will not lead to collisions. Not being able to control the namespace of the AVRO record from the JSON Schema is a little bit of a shame, as it feels like you're just about there, but I haven't been able to dig deep enough to offer a solution.

The suggested SMT SetSchemaMetadata (see first reply to the question) can be useful in this process, but [it's documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/setschemametadata.html) clashes a little with AVRO naming conventions as it shows `order-value` in an example. It will try to find a schema that contains an AVRO record with this name as the root element and since '-' is an illegal character in an AVRO name, you get an error. If you use the correct name of the root element, though, the SMT does something very useful: Its `RestService` class, which queries the Schema Registry to find a matching schema, fails with a message printing out the exact schema definition that needs to be created, so you don't necessarily have to memorize all the transformation rules.

Thus the answer to the original question is: Yes, it can be done with Kafka Connect. And it also is the best way to go if you

- don't want to write your own producer/connector
- want to store JSON blobs in a typed way as opposed to converting them after they hit an initial topic

If conversion after data ingestion is an option, the [de-, re- and serialization capabilities of ksqlDB](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/serialization/#json) seem to be quite powerful.